# How to use ProgressUpdate(Integer... values) in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new in android and i want to know that can we pass string as param in this  method in ProgressUpdate(Integer... values)

Comment: assuming that you're talking about AsyncTask ... you have to: learn java first(generic types) then read documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html ... then you should be able to change it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onProgressUpdate()` with any reference types, for that you need to specify `String` as the type of progress in `AsyncTask`, for example:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>
```

As you probably know, first generic argument in `AsyncTask` is used for input parameters' type, second is used for progress, and the last one indicates of which type will the result be. Hope this helps.